# How do I get a number inside a div element to decrement based on an non matching number entered in text field?

Tags: javascript

I wanted to first say that I am new as new can get to javascript. I am trying to do a remake of the number guessing game where I have a div with a number in it that I want decreased when I guess wrong. I have been able to get the game to print out a message saying whether I guessed right or wrong, but I can't get it to decrement the number in the other div box I created. I tried to use parseInt, but I feel that I'm so new that I am way off. I had already pre-assigned a number inside the div, but I'm assuming that it is in string form and must somehow be converted before I can even decrease it.

I have a simple text field(for entering the guessed number attempt), a message field above it in a div, a div below that shows the number I guessed after entered, and a div with guesses left. I gave up and deleted the code, any help would be appreciated. I just want to know how to decrease that guesses left number from 10 to below when I've guessed wrong.

Comment: Have you tried something so far? If yes please share your code.

Comment: Please make this a [mcve]

Comment: Yeah, I erased the original code, but I can try to explain what I was trying to do. I was trying to do the number guessing game on my own and I've got very very little experience messing with javascript. I essentially put a text input field with a class name, then a message div section tied to a class, then another div with a 10 in it. I was trying to set it up so that it would deduct from the 10(guesses left) when I guessed wrong in the text field. I can't figure out how to get the number to lower more or less, i got the message fields to work telling me I am right or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit your guess number in your form, you'll need to update the "guesses remaining" value. Just have your HTML display the value.toString() and update the value in JS using a click handler on your form (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick). This should get you moving in the right direction.

That form submission should also validate your input answer btw.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to put everything into one function because I'm new and don't really know what to do yet, just messing around. I tried to do that but I noticed that it seemed like you couldn't do more than one thing or two at a time when I used an if statement. I probably went about everything the wrong way. I tried to use a ++ on like the variable.value, but it never decreased anything. I think at best I got something that said NaN as in not a number in place of the number of guesses left in the box.

Comment: @gamer_geek7519044 you can absolutely do more than one thing in an if statement. if(x) { f(x); g(x); return x; } // what you can't do is have more than one return statement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I winded up figuring it out what I wanted to know last light :). I should have gotten an account here much sooner, this place is nice.